# Cuda C++ design: reusable class with unknown compile-time size

Tags: c++, class, memory-management, dynamic, cuda

I am looking for a convenient design in order to be able to use a class on the device which has unknown compile-time size.
Only one instance of this class needs to be sent to the device, for which there should be a single call to cudaMalloc and cudaMemcpy (ideally).

The host version of the class would look like this:

```
Class A {
public:
A(int size) : table(size) {
 // some useful initialization of table
}
double get(int i) const {
  // return some processed element from table 
}
private:
std::vector<int> table;
};
```

The kernel:

```
__global__ void kernel(const A *a){
  int idx = threadIdx.x + blockDim.x * blockIdx.x;
  a->get(idx);  // do something useful with it
}
```

So far, the way I would design the device version of the class is like that:

```
const int sizeMax = 1000;
Class A {
public:
A(int size) {
 // size checking + some useful initialization of table
}
__host__ __device__
double get(int i) const {
  // 
}
private:
int table[sizeMax];
};
```

And the client code:

```
A a(128);
A* da;
cudaMalloc((void**)&da, sizeof(A));
cudaMemcpy(da, &a, sizeof(A), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
kernel<<<1, 32>>>(da);
cudaDeviceSynchronize();
cudaFree(da);
```

This is rather ugly because:

- it wastes bandwith by having to use too large a sizeMax in order to
  be on the safe side
- the class is not closed for modification, the value of sizeMax will
  inevitably need to be raised at some point

Is there any other way to achieve the same thing in a cleaner way without negative performance impact? To be clear, I only need the device version of the class, the first version is just the equivalent non-CUDA code to illustrate the fact that the table size should be dynamic.

Comment: 1. separate host and device storage for `table`, contained in the class, both of which are allocated dynamically.  2. dynamic allocation of table storage size in the constructor, rather than in your client code.  This could also include resizing if necessary.  3. differentiation in class methods to use either the host copy of the data or the device copy (i.e. pointer) to the data, depending on whether the method is being executed in host or device code   4. A method to copy data from host to device or vice versa, as the class context is moved from host to device or vice versa.

Comment: another approach: [CUDA managed (i.e. unified) memory](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/unified-memory-in-cuda-6/)

Comment: @RobertCrovella on point 2, so that means implementing ``std::vector`` functionality by the user itself? what about using ``thrust::device_vector<int>`` like implementations?

Comment: @BAdhi: No, it means allocating some memory at runtime and assigning the address of that memory to a pointer in the structure, And no thrust::device_vector couldn't be used because it isn't supported in device code.

Answer (score 1):

In my comment, I said:

> 1. separate host and device storage for table, contained in the class, both of which are allocated dynamically. 2. dynamic allocation of table storage size in the constructor, rather than in your client code. This could also include resizing if necessary. 3. differentiation in class methods to use either the host copy of the data or the device copy (i.e. pointer) to the data, depending on whether the method is being executed in host or device code 4. A method to copy data from host to device or vice versa, as the class context is moved from host to device or vice versa.

Here's an example of what I had in mind:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda_runtime_api.h>
#include <iostream>


template <typename T>
class gpuvec{
  private:
    T *h_vec = NULL;
    T *d_vec = NULL;
    size_t vsize = 0;
    bool iscopy;
  public:
    __host__ __device__
    T * data(){
      #ifndef __CUDA_ARCH__
        return h_vec;
      #else
        return d_vec;
      #endif
      }
    __host__ __device__
    T& operator[](size_t i) {
      assert(i < vsize);
        return data()[i];}
    void to_device(){
      assert(cudaMemcpy(d_vec, h_vec, vsize*sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) == cudaSuccess);}
    void to_host(){
      assert(cudaMemcpy(h_vec, d_vec, vsize*sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost) == cudaSuccess);}
    gpuvec(gpuvec &o){
      h_vec = o.h_vec;
      d_vec = o.d_vec;
      vsize = o.vsize;
      iscopy = true;}
    void copy(gpuvec &o){
      free();
      iscopy = false;
      vsize = o.vsize;
      h_vec = (T *)malloc(vsize*sizeof(T));
      assert(h_vec != NULL);
      assert(cudaMalloc(&d_vec, vsize*sizeof(T)) == cudaSuccess);
      memcpy(h_vec, o.h_vec, vsize*sizeof(T));
      assert(cudaMemcpy(d_vec, o.d_vec, vsize*sizeof(T), cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice) == cudaSuccess);}
    gpuvec(size_t ds) {
      assert(ds > 0);
      iscopy = false;
      vsize = ds;
      h_vec = (T *)malloc(vsize*sizeof(T));
      assert(h_vec != NULL);
      assert(cudaMalloc(&d_vec, vsize*sizeof(T)) == cudaSuccess);}
    gpuvec(){
      iscopy = false;
    }
    ~gpuvec(){
      if (!iscopy) free();}
    void free(){
      if (d_vec != NULL) cudaFree(d_vec); 
      d_vec = NULL;
      if (h_vec != NULL) ::free(h_vec);
      h_vec = NULL;}
    __host__ __device__
    size_t size() {
      return vsize;}
};

template <typename T>
__global__ void test(gpuvec<T> d){
  for (int i = 0; i < d.size(); i++){
    d[i] += 1;
    }
}


int main(){
  size_t ds = 10;
  gpuvec<int>  A(ds);
  A.to_device();
  test<<<1,1>>>(A);
  A.to_host();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < ds; i++)
    std::cout << A[i];
  std::cout << std::endl;
  gpuvec<int> B;
  B.copy(A);
  A.free();
  B.to_device();
  test<<<1,1>>>(B);
  B.to_host();
  for (size_t i = 0; i < ds; i++)
    std::cout << B[i];
  std::cout << std::endl;
  B.free();
}
```

I'm sure quite a few criticisms could be made.  This may not adhere to any particular opinion of what "vector syntax" should be.  Furthermore I'm sure there are use cases it does not cover, and it may contain outright defects.   To create a robust host/device vector realization may require as much work and complexity as [thrust](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/thrust/index.html) host and device vectors.  I'm not suggesting that thrust vectors are a drop-in answer for what the question seems to be asking, however.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Robert Crovella's answer, here is a simplified (device only, so ignoring points 3 & 4) working solution:

```
Class A {
public:
A(int size) : table(size) {
 // some useful initialization of table
 cudaMalloc((void**)&dTable, sizeof(int) * size);
 cudaMemcpy(dTable, &table[0], sizeof(int) * size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
}
~A() {
cudaFree(dTable);
}
__device__
double get(int i) const {
  // return some processed element of dTable 
}
private:
std::vector<int> table;
int *dTable; 
};
```

Kernel and client code stay exactly the same.